# Javascript Cookie to Submit form only once

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am trying to submit my form once automatically on page load using JS cookies and following is my code but its not working. Any help would be appreciable. Thank you.
I am doubtful with my code related to setting and getting cookies.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
      window.onload = function()
      {
        if(window.location == "hello.html")
        {       
            alert("location match");
            var x = getCookie("crmodtaskform");
            alert("cookie retrieved");
            alert("x:" + x);
            if(x == "")
            {
                setCookie("crmodtaskform",yes);
                alert("cookie set");
                document.checkform.submit();
            }
            else
            {
               alert("cookie is already set and form already submiteed once");
            }
        }
      }

     function setCookie(cname,cvalue)
     {
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";";
     }

     function getCookie(cname)
     {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
        {
           var c = ca[i].trim();
           if (c.indexOf(name)==0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
        return "";
     }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <form    name="checkform" method="POST">
    First Name: <input type="text" id="fn"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: why do you need cookies to submit a form on page load?!

Comment: This piece of code is just sample. My purpose is different. I want to submit form once on loading page. Kindly let me know why my cookie is not working?

Comment: From the looks of it, what  you want to do is to submit a form only once, next time when the document is loaded again and the same form is submitted you need to prevent submission since the form is already submitted, is that right?

Comment: Yes. In my actual application I have access only to header and in body there is cascading dropdown list. To make that dropdown cascade I need to submit form once on page load.

Answer (score 0):

`if(window.location == "hello.html")` will never be true. When you stringify `location` it will be the *complete* URI not just the last component of the path segment.

Compare to the whole URI, or use `indexOf()` or `match()`

Comment: I just removed the complete address.. I am aware of it. My code runs till alerting x. which means its entering if loop on matching location.